# How to use a Switch to switch from Wifi Access Point mode to STA in esp32

Tags: c, wifi, arduino-ide, esp32, sta

I am doing an autonomous car project, I need manual control as well as an autonomous function, so the manual control is done through wifi using "gesture control" and for the autonomous control I want to send the location data via an HTTP request, but then I have to switch to an STA mode, so I want to use a Toggle switch connected to ground and a pin as input and put it in an "if statement", but all of the initial setups come in the void setup(), so I don't know how to proceed I have provided the AP part of the main code I am using

```
#include <esp_now.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_wifi.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>          // Tiny GPS Plus Library 


#define CHANNEL 4

uint8_t mac[] = {0x36, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33};

struct __attribute__((packed)) DataStruct {
    //char text[32];
    int x;
    int y;
    unsigned long time;
};

DataStruct myData;

  //**********************************************
// GPS Locations

unsigned long Distance_To_Home;                                    // variable for storing the distance to destination

int ac =0;                                                         // GPS array counter
int wpCount = 0;                                                   // GPS waypoint counter
double Home_LATarray[50];                                          // variable for storing the destination Latitude - Only Programmed for 5 waypoint
double Home_LONarray[50];                                          // variable for storing the destination Longitude - up to 50 waypoints

int increment = 0;

#define autopilot 13
 void  gesturecontroll();
 void getGPS();    
 void getCompass();  

void setWaypoint();

 void move();

 int blueToothVal;  


void setup() 
{    Serial.begin(9600);                                            // Serial 0 is for communication with the computer
     S2.begin(9600);                                             // Serial 2 is for GPS communication at 9600 baud - DO NOT MODIFY - Ublox Neo 6m 


 Serial.println("ESPNow/Basic/Slave Example");
  //Set device in AP mode to begin with
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  // configure device AP mode
  // This is the mac address of the Slave in AP Mode
  esp_wifi_set_mac(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &mac[0]);


  Serial.print("AP MAC: "); Serial.println(WiFi.softAPmacAddress());
  // Init ESPNow with a fallback logic
  if (esp_now_init()!=0) {
        Serial.println("*** ESP_Now init failed");
        while(true) {};
    }

  // Once ESPNow is successfully Init, we will register for recv CB to
  // get recv packer info.
  esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);
   Serial.print("Aheloiioi");


 // Extras////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     pinMode(autopilot, INPUT);



}
void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t *mac_addr, const uint8_t *data, int data_len) {
  memcpy(&myData, data, sizeof(myData));
  char macStr[18];
  snprintf(macStr, sizeof(macStr), "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
           mac_addr[0], mac_addr[1], mac_addr[2], mac_addr[3], mac_addr[4], mac_addr[5]);
  Serial.print("Last Packet Recv from: "); Serial.println(macStr);
  Serial.print("Last Packet Recv Data: "); 
  Serial.println(myData.x); 
  Serial.println(myData.y);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println();
  //move();
  Serial.println();
} 

//********************************************************************************************************
// Main Loop

void loop()
{ if (autopilot == HIGH)
    {
      // going for manual control, BUT WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?

      } 
  else
  { 
    getGPS();                                                        // Update the GPS location
    getCompass();                                                    // Update the CompaSerial Heading
    Ping();                                                          // Use at your own discretion, this is not fully tested

    }    

}
```